# Refrescar grid y pintar

Tags: delphi, pascal, delphi-2010, delphi-berlin, delphi-tokyo

estoy intentado refrescar un grid al cual darle doble click me actualice el color de unas determinadas filas.

Por ejemplo,en este caso lo que hago es doble click en el grid y lo recorro y el valor del primer campo lo comparo con el valor de ese 
campo que proviene de una query...

El caso es que en determinado caso,cuando sean iguales los valores,quiero que pinte de rojo toda esa fila...

El caso es que se me vuelve loco y me lo pinta todo y no entiendo que pasa.

Dejo código:

```
procedure TAvisosUrgentes.JvDBUltimGrid1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
var x: Integer;     //Indice para recorrer la query de Refresco
aviso:Variant; //Variable Aviso actual al recorrer el Dataset
ds :TDataSet; //Variable de la fuente de datos

begin

FDQRefrescar.Active:=false;
FDQRefrescar.Active:=true;
FDQRefrescar.Close;
FDQRefrescar.Open;
FDQRefrescar.RecordCount;


ds:=JvDBUltimGrid1.DataSource.DataSet;
ds.First;
  while (not ds.Eof) do begin

    aviso:= JvDBUltimGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.FieldByName('CODAVS').Value;

    for x:=0 to FDQRefrescar.recordcount -1 do begin
        if FDQRefrescar.FieldByName('CODAVS').Value= aviso then
        begin
       AQUI DEBE IR EL PINTADO DE LA FILA
        FDQRefrescar.Next;
        end;
    end;
    ds.Next;
    FDQRefrescar.First;
  end;
```

end;

Answer (score 1):

Yo creo que te estás complicando más de lo necesario.
Por un lado no veo la necesidad de pulsar **"doble click para "pintar"** cuando ya está dibujando el `DBGrid` y tienes toda la información necesaria para hacerlo.

Por otro lado, en el código que has puesto, estás haciendo un recorrido cuando para "pintar" el propio `DBGrid` ya se están recorriendo los datos, y volvemos al punto anterior, no es necesario.

Te muestro un ejemplo con los datos que vienen por defecto con los ejemplos de Delphi. 
En esta caso la condición es ***"pintar de color diferente las filas cuyo campo POPULATION tiene un (valor > 10000000)"***. No debe ser dificil que lo adaptes a tus datos con la condición que desees.

El evento que debes programar es el que trae el `DBGrid` para pintar celdas (`OnDrawColumnCell`).
Con el siguiente código:

```
procedure TForm5.DBGrid1DrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject; const Rect: TRect;
  DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumn; State: TGridDrawState);
var
  f:TField;
begin
  // Acceder al campo que tiene el dato que quieres como referencia para pintar
  f := Column.Field.DataSet.FieldByName('Population');
  // Si lo encuentro, continuo
  if Assigned(f) then begin
    // Valor para la condición de si PINTAR o NO
    if (f.AsInteger > 10000000)  then
      DBGrid1.Canvas.Brush.Color := clInfoBk          // color a pintar
    else
      DBGrid1.Canvas.Brush.Color := DbGrid1.Color;   //  color definido en el grid

    // Pinto la celda del color seleccionado
    DBGrid1.DefaultDrawColumnCell(Rect, DataCol, Column, State);
  end;
end;
```

Obtendrás lo siguiente (las filas que cumplen la condición sobre el campo POPULATION se habrán pintado de otro color):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debería bastar por cambiar el campo `"Population"` y la condición de `Valor>100000000`, por lo que tú necesites, para obtener algo similar.